# Replace word typing with image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, web

I want whenever user typing a word that show corresponding an image on the text box (images that stored from local folder). But I don't know how to do that. I'm beginner in javascript

For Example: If I type A will show the image A, B will show image B, C will show image C...

this is image show what I want

[image]

this 26 letter images
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DjfwyYniynenBnntlO7jqhvPm4uDpOvu?usp=sharing

Thanks.

This my code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
            <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0' />
            </head>
                <body>
                <div id='editor' contenteditable='true' style='white-space: pre-line;'>
                </div>
                </body>
        </html>"
```

Comment: So you have images for every character?

Comment: The least you can do is tell us which word corresponds to which image.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yep. images that  in local

Comment: @Spectric I have edited my question, example : Type A will show image A, Type B will show image B...

Comment: @Sasaki It would also be helpful if you actually provided the images.

Comment: @Spectric I have attached image link, do you see that?

Comment: @Sasaki Images, as in, the images for the letter A, B, C etc,.

Comment: Have you investigated the various events associated with the user pressing a key?

Comment: @AHaworth yes I did. I could get pressing key but I don't know how to replace it. I'm beginner Javascript

Comment: @Spectric I have attached images folder link